# No foreign key constraints and need to do a complicated delete

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a website which I have been working on creating very rapidly, and now am paying back some technical debt.  I have a complicated issue:

My site deals with scheduling hikes.  Once you create a hike, it has many things associated with it:
a message board, list of attendees, the group it belongs to, the carpool, route, trailhead, etc.

Here is an example so you can see what I am talking about:
http://www.comehike.com/hikes/scheduled_hike.php?hike_id=172

The technical debt I am talking about is that I never made foreign keys in the DB, and now need to do a cascade delete, and I am not sure how to go about it so that I don't introduce a million bugs :)

Should I make foreign keys for all the tables now?  How should I do this?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered - very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the MySQL docs on [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).  Note that you'll need to be using innoDB tables.

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename>
ADD CONSTRAINT <fkname> FOREIGN KEY <index name>(<columns>)
REFERENCES <othertable> (<columns>)
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: ctually, what are innoDB? I keep seeing that pop up here and there, but not sure what exactly that is :)

Comment: InnoDB is an alternate storage engine for MySQL - the default storage engine is 'quick and dirty'.  InnoDB supports transactions, foreign keys etc. - it's somewhat slower for some operations, but is more robust.

Comment: h, I see.  Also, just kind of a dumb question - which direction does the foreign key go?  If I have a hike table and a hike_attendee table, which table gets the foreign key?

Comment: The foreign key goes onto the table that references the primary key of 'the other table'.  So from e.g. attendee -> hike, FK goes on attendee.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating foreign keys for the tables in your DB. This will be a more robust way of dealing with the problem you are facing. You obviously understand what a foreign key imposes on the database, and how to deal with the keys.

If I was faced with this problem, I would use a graphical interface for the database if I had one (e.g. PhpMyAdmin), otherwise a quick google brings up some [tutorials](http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_Create_foreign_key_contraints.php).

---

EDIT: From the linked tutorial, in a many-to-one relationship, you pace the key on the "many" table, indicating that a certain column in that table can only have values that are present in a certain column in the "one" table. Hi the link for a worked example.

When adding keys to a table that already has data, you may not be able to add the foreign key if some of the data is malformed. For example, if you have a phone number table referencing a person table (many phone numbers to one person) and you have any phone numbers with an invalid person_id (maybe person 5 was deleted and there is still a phone number with a person_id of 5) you will be unable to create the foreign key until you remove the offending phone number.

Answer (score 1):

if you have not made formal foreign keys, the have you made the keys some other way that permits linking the tables or are all tables unrelated ?

If there is anyway to relate the tables then you will simply have to write a Cascading Delete code.

Otherwise its probabely a redesign or add in foreignkey fun. =))

If you have not already get yourself a copy of MySQL Workbench and redesign it from there adding in the foreign keys. This will generate the SQL code for you too.

Comment: I just kind of kept in my head what unique key the tables had and made my queries and joins based on those.  Actually I am being dumb, but which direction is the foreign key supposed to go?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with creating foreign keys as well but if there is any reason that stops you from doing so there is another solution which is creating Triggers. You can tell triggers to basically do anything you want when an update,delete or insertion occurs to a table in the database including changing other tuples in other tables. Here are a couple of tutorials on how to create triggers:

http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/statements_7004.htm
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

the first one seems more direct and clearer but if none of them helps just search google for DB triggers and you're all set!

I hope this helps :)